# Can i add a slide to hidden div when button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html

Can i add like a slide to the hidden divs when they disappear ?
I want the div to slide when it disappears

Like this:

1. Button press
2. The hidden div slides in
3. Button press again
4. the div disappears with a slide to the side

How can i do that ?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/hide/

Comment: You can find many answers to your question by simply googling this. Please do some more research before posting a question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

[Here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions) is a good tutorial for sliding things in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example using `jQuery`:

**[Check the JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/46Vc5/)**

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Include the jQuery Library -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Our DOM Structure for the javascript using jQuery -->
        <div id="theDiv">This is a div!</div>
        <button id="myButton">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// When the page is ready and loaded
$(function(){
    // On click of "myButton"
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        // "slideToggle" the div
        // ie: If hidden show it, else hide it
        $('#theDiv').slideToggle();
    });
})
</script>
```

[View the jQuery `slideToggle` docs here](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

---

If you've never used jQuery before, check out:
     http://learn.jquery.com/
     http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32 (Video tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery or another library. You can also write your own function but it would take a while.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery functions slideUp(), slideDown() and slideToggle() should help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/944sE/ <--- where do i put in that ?

Comment: Instead of lists[i].style.display = 'none'; use lists[i].slideUp(); for example

Answer (score 0):

well if wanting to do this with pure javascript it would take a bit of coding or you can use jquery and use the baked in animations.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

## button : assuming this to be your button id

## data : div which is to be played

```
//include jquery

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#button').click(function(){
  $('#data').toggle('slow',function(){ });
 )};
});
```