# Close div when new div opens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a slide but how do i get that only one div opens and when i open another the recent div closes and the new opens ?

```
$(function(){
$('#myButton1').click(function(){
    $('#theDiv1').slideToggle();
});})
```

I have six more of those in the real script.

Comment: what you looking for is called accordion

Comment: @vittore said is right use `accordian` may this help http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: But, if you don't want to use an accordion, I can show you how to open one and close the others, let me know :)

Comment: yeah, that would be cool, will it be like twitter ?

Comment: you couldn't figure this out after your last question less then 30 mins ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126211/can-i-add-a-slide-to-hidden-div-when-button-is-pressed

Answer (score 1):

Close all in a common function and open the one to open where you are.

```
$(function(){
    $('#myButton1').click(function(){
      closeAllDivs();
      $('#theDiv1').slideToggle();
    });
})
```

Meanwhile, in some other part of file...

```
function closeAllDivs(){
      $('#theDiv1').slideIn(); //Down/up/in/out whatever...
      $('#theDiv2').slideIn();
      $('#theDiv3').slideIn();
      $('#theDiv4').slideIn();
      $('#theDiv5').slideIn();
      $('#theDiv6').slideIn(); 
}
```

There are more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myButton1').click(function(){
      $(document).find('div').each(function(){$(this).slideIn();});
      $('#theDiv1').slideToggle();
    });
})
```